# Simplify a polynomial in $e^{i\omega}$ without using trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, complex-numbers

Given $z=e^{\omega i}$, the following polynomial can be reduced to a quadratic using trigonometry.

$$
P_0 (z^3 - z^{-3}) + P_1 (z^2 - z^{-2}) + P_2 (z^1 - z^{-1})
$$

One method is to exploit the relationship of $e^{\omega i}$ with trigonometry and rewrite as:

$$
P_0\sin(3x) + P_1\sin(2x) + P_2\sin(x) = 0
$$

Which ultimately leads to a solution in powers of $sin(\omega)$.

This involves quite a lot of trigonometric identity manipulation from this point on. Is there a nicer way that arrives at a quadratic in powers of $sin(\omega)$ without using lots of intermediate trigonometry?

Comment: $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x=2\sin x\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ is not a polynomial in $\sin x$. (On the other hand, it is generically true that $\dfrac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$ is a polynomial in $\cos x$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After factoring out $z-z^{-1}$ you get
$$
P_0(z^2+1+z^{-2})+P_1(z+z^{-1})+P_2=
P_0(z+z^{-1})^2+P_1(z+z^{-1})+P_2-P_0
$$
so a polynomial in $z+z^{-1}=2\cos\omega$, that is easy to compute the roots of.

Comment: slight correction: $P_0(z^2 + 2 + z^{-2}) + ... - 2 P_0$ ;-)

Comment: @keith $z^3-z^{-3}=(z-z^{-1})(z^2+1+z^{-2})$

Comment: I know that, but $(z+z^{−1})^2 = z^2+z^{−2} + 2$ rhs of your equation

Comment: @keith Yes, and so? I add $P_0$ and subtract $P_0$, so the first summand becomes $P_0(z^2+2+z^{-2})=P_0(z+z^{-1})^2$ and there's just $-P_0$ remaining.

Comment: ah yes I see, I am applying it to a different situation now, you are correct :-)